# cURL in PHP not retrieving a response

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to load a page from another website in PHP so that I can scrape its content. This works with pretty much any other web page, but for some reason it doesn't work with this one:

http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100022286&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=CS&courseDisplayName=103&sectionDisplayName=01

Anybody know why? Is it a firewall or something?
Or know of another way to go about doing this? Even in another language?

Here's the cURL code I'm using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $theurl);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've tried these cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , *ports 22 and 433*);
```

** Know of any other ports to try? Or a way to figure out which port the host is using? I'm trying to loop thru possible ports right now.

I've tried getting the info and here's what I've got:

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
```

returns

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100022286&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=CS&courseDisplayName=103§ionDisplayName=01 [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 289 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.602861 [namelookup_time] => 0.226121 [connect_time] => 0.285047 [pretransfer_time] => 0.285149 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.602824 [redirect_time] => 0 )
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Looks like the site is down or inaccessible from here too so that might explain it? The site is probably firewalled indeed.

Comment: I have `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` so I think its problem on there site.

Comment: Site is down here too (Netherlands). It would explain a lot :)

Comment: Hmm site is not down for me -- must be a country firewall. I'm in California.

Comment: I get the same curl response as @piotrekkr -- thanks for the comments, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that the web admins must not have enabled CORS. To scrape the page I wrote a Java bot that loaded the page in my browser and saved it to a file. Messy but it ultimately worked...